# Getting list of ID's of selected items into field of another table

Tags: qgis-3

I've been struggling with this for a while and about to give up so hoping someone will be able to help.

I have a point table of trees (Trees) and another representing individual orders (WorksOrders) which basically has a point for an individual order for raising work on one or more trees.

What I'd like is to select a number of trees from the Trees layer and return the id's of the selected features to a single field in my WorkOrders table.

I'm really stuck - is it possible at all? I'm not a coder and have no Python knowledge and really no wish to start coding!

Comment: Is your WorksOrders layer a point layer? it would be easier if it was a polygon layer, you could return the Id's of the trees within the polygons with a simple expression. If your WorkOrder layer has to be a point layer, you'll have to give the trees an attribute wich would connect them to a corresponding WorkOrder.

Comment: Hi LeoC. It's not a polygon layer and there is a one to many relationship between the works order and tree layers s trees can be worked on more than once but a works order will be created one time. I can pick all the trees and get a list of the selected with the is_selected() function, I just don't know hoe to transfer their ID's to a field in the works order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a default expression for the *trees ID's* field in the WorkOrder layer (let's say **"trees_ids"**).
You would first select the trees and then create the WorkOrder point. All the selected trees Id's would appear in the "trees_ids" field.
here's the expression:

```
aggregate(layer:='trees', 
  aggregate:='concatenate', 
  expression:="tree_id", --< id field in the tree layer
  filter:= is_selected( 'trees', 
          get_feature('trees', 'tree_id', "tree_id")),
  concatenator:=','
  )
```

The id field in the trees layer cannot be called "id", I don't know why. It works with "tree_id" though.
If your layer are shape files, be carefull because there is a limit to how much characters can fit in a text attribute (something like 250).
This method works but it might be more simple if the WorkOrder layer was a polygon layer. You would'nt have to select the trees but just to draw a polygon around the concerned trees.

Comment: Thanks Leo. I know what you mean about using a polygon layer but this will be for someone that is not particularly GIS savvy so can't trust them to get the polygon to cover the correct trees so just having a point is safer!

Comment: Actually, I've just thought of something! Get the Worksorder polygon to creat based of the MBR of the selected objects - that might be the way to go.

Comment: Update: Leo's solution was very slow so I looked at doing it another way - within "Default" value area of the field in the dialog I've entered "array_to_string(overlay_intersects('Trees', ref))" which is dynamic but is super quick. Just thought I'd drop that in here for information. Thanks to LeaC for the idea.